# Can't check if the request succeed or not

Tags: javascript, html, logging, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to create a JavaScript code that allows me to check if I can send an HTTP request to the given host, through an URL (check if the server on or not). This is my code:

```js
<html>
<body>
<script>
  function checkServer(url) {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;
  const options = { mode: 'no-cors', signal };
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(setTimeout(() => { controller.abort() }, 5))
    .then(response => function() 
    {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open("GET", "http://log.mywebsite.com", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    )
    .catch(error => function() 
    {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open("POST", "http://log.mywebsite.com", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    )
  }
  checkServer('https://blahdummydamnfck.com');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But, although it can't send the HTTP request to the server, it didn't send a log request to my log server. Why is this happening with me?

Answer (score 0):

the fetch does not throw. It returns an error code if the request fails, so catch is not the right way to detect a missing server. Check the [response code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) instead

from the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):
*The fetch() method takes one mandatory argument, the path to the resource you want to fetch. It returns a Promise that resolves to the Response to that request, whether it is successful or not. You can also optionally pass in an init options object as the second argument (see Request).*

Comment: Then what is your suggestion?

Comment: `fetch(url, options).then(function(response) { if (response.status == "200") then { okay } else { not okay };});`

Comment: or responce.ok. @EthicalHackerMinh read the docs mate. It helps most of the times.

Comment: It gave me this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'` at `then {`